# Splash screen for universal windows 10 apps

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, splash-screen, windows-10-mobile

I am creating a windows 10 universal app targeted for both Windows Phones and Windows Desktop, the problem I am facing on is when adding splash screen through the package.manifest file to the app, there is no option to add splash screen which fits the phone's portrait orientation (see the image below),

[image]

And when I deploy the app on the phone the splash screen appears like shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, you will also want to specify the *Background color*, on your first screenshot.

Read this -

> For a Windows Phone Store app, provide the 2.4x asset at a minimum;
>   preferably all. The image file assets themselves should have a
>   transparent background. In your app manifest, set the value of the
>   SplashScreen@Image property to "Assets\.png", and set a
>   value for VisualElements@BackgroundColor.

You can read more from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx).

The first half of the link seems to be talking about splash screens in the Windows 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1, including the paragraph I quoted above, but the same rules apply to Windows 10. I don't think you can have a full page splash screen given all the different sized devices. Previously it would still be possible 'cause you could simply remove the splash screen and create a xaml startup usercontrol within your app, but since the splash screen becomes mandatory in UWP, I just don't see any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Which means, that effectively you can only design a small part in the center? I hope there's a better solution...

Comment: Yeah, I was also wondering what the background was for. Thanks for the help

Comment: A full screen splash screen image can be set for Windows Phone 8.1 apps; all my WP 8.1 apps have such splash screen. I'm facing the same problem though on Windows 10 Mobile/UWP.

Comment: For Windows 10, you should not need 2.4x assets (or 1.4 or 1.8) like in Windows 8.1. For Windows 10, you need, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0, 4.0. (They changed the possible scale factors). If you don't want to support 5 different factors, provide the 2.0x asset.

Comment: I have the same question. But I'm wondering if I can use images that meet the ratio of portrait view in phone without adding splash screen extension. This is because the wide icons we got look horrible if put directly in the portrait view. We also got some icons that has portrait view's ratio that were specifically designed for phones. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make an advanced splash screen with a **bigger image** and **ProgessBar** or a **ProgressRing** . You should check Msdn on "**how to extend the splash screen**".

You can read more about the [Extended splash screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx) here.

Best of luck !

Comment: This is really the best way to think about it. The basic images aren't intended as being full size covers, just logos in a color space.

Comment: This works but the image is displayed very large in Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing similar problem. The splash screen I show has portrait orientation. It should have content in the upper and the lower part of the screen. 
So I found an article in internet explaining how to implement an extended splash screen.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-and-extended-splash-screen/

Following that article I just referenced my splash screen having size 300x620. It works fine though Visual Studio marks the image as invalid.

[image: Invalid Splash Screen Size]