# Is there any way to to load images with different ratios instead of making extended splash screen in UWP?

Tags: xaml, icons, uwp

In VS, it seems that you can only upload images with ratio 1240:600 for splash screen. 
[image]

This ratio is good for wide screen, but looks horrible in phone. Like this link shows [Splash screen for universal windows 10 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201551/splash-screen-for-universal-windows-10-apps) I got some images that have better ratio to display on phone.

[image]

I know that you can make an extended screen to show, however, it still looks not so good using this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-and-extended-splash-screen/. I'm wondering if there is any other way that allow you to use the portrait view images directly. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, can you reproduce this issue on mobile emulator? Which device are you using to test this issue?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Actually it's not about reproducing the issue. What I want to do is that I'm wondering if there is anyway to load portrait view pictures and landscape view pictures as splash screen for different sizes screen (like phone use portrait and tablet use landscape).

Comment: I'm afraid no way in UWP, but it will scale on different device, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT In 8.1 you can load different pictures for phone and desktop projects. In UWP I highly suggest MSFT introduce load splash screen with portrait and landscape. This is because even it auto resizes, icons look good in one ratio may not look good in another ratio. Also it will limit the way people design their icons. But thanks for your help, Grace.